# finding something in a list of collections based on key?

Tags: groovy

I am new to JAVA and Groovy, but I have the following data:

"[[260000032:32129, 1000000001:THIS CUSTOMER], [260000032:194571, 1000000001:THAT CUSTOMER], [260000032:201432, 1000000001:ANOTHER CUSTOMER]]"

I would like for example to find "THIS CUSTOMER" when I search for "32129".

I tried a lot of approach but failed.:/

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far and explain what is the core problem you are facing. You have posted an input and some values you are trying to get in the end, but your question lacks information about [mcve].

Comment: Your data looks suspiciosly like a toString() of a map. You are most likely better off preventing this in the first place. toString is a very dangerous route to serialize data and usually a bug.

Comment: cfrick: i receive this data as is sadly, is there a proper way to reverse it?

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    [260000032:32129,  1000000001:"THIS CUSTOMER"],
    [260000032:194571, 1000000001:"THAT CUSTOMER"],
    [260000032:201432, 1000000001:"ANOTHER CUSTOMER"]
]
 .find { it.getAt(260000032) == 32129 }
 .getAt(1000000001)
```

Edit: My answer assumed you already had the objects. But if your data is really just a string in a non-standard format (i.e. it has string literals without quotes), you might need to do something ugly like parse with Regex.

```
def input = "[[260000032:32129, 1000000001:THIS CUSTOMER], [260000032:194571, 1000000001:THAT CUSTOMER], [260000032:201432, 1000000001:ANOTHER CUSTOMER]]"

(input =~ /\[260000032\:([^\,]+),\s1000000001\:([^\]]+)/)
 .collect { it }
 .collectEntries { [(it[1]): it[2]] }
 .getAt('32129')
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy,

this worked however my source has not got double quotes :/

Is there a way to make it work? Cheers

Comment: Ok, I added another approach. Is your data really in that format? Be careful what you are asking.

Comment: unfortunatelly it is, kindof silly i know, i should perhaps post a new query on how to turn such dodgy data into a proper format. As i need to have a more reusable approach instead as I might have other keys there